# Can I upgrade the Omni-Tool?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I know in past games you were able to upgrade your Omni-Tool for engineer type classes.

In the codex for this game, it mentioned that even soldiers will take to modifying their tools (an example of this is the first ever use of an Omni-Tool by my soldier as a kinda awesome, but somewhat useless knife).

The question is simple, due to this mention of the codex, I expect this to be available but I have not seen anything even hinting to an Omni-Tool upgrade like a better knife or even a sword of some sort.  So are these upgrades in the game, or is this more of a  plot hole in the codex and we are being lied to where the new heavy melee feature only has this knife for the entire game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly, but several powers allow you to increase your melee damage.

I'm pretty sure what the codex is talking about is how each class has customized their omni tool (it's a sword for Infiltrator, a big ball of energy punch for Infiltrator...) so the strong-melee weapon is different for each class, thus their omnitool has been modified.

There is no "omni tool upgrade" option or item.

Comment: Aww boo, I was hoping to get a giant FF7-Cloud Sword for my soldier =[

Answer (score 1):

Each class has customized their omni-blade as follows:

- **Sentinels** - Double bladed slash
- **Infiltrators** - Shocking Slash
- **Vanguard** - Biotic Ball Haymaker Punch
- **Adept** - Biotic Meleeing Shot
- **Soldier** - Dagger Stab
- **Engineer** - Flaming Arc

These attacks can not be modified outside of a class change.